# Simplifying square roots of squared reals

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am using Mathematica to check some long, tedious calculations and I am stumped by some mysterious behavior. If I simplify a long expression that clearly has square real factors under a radical, for some reason `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` will not extract them even if I declare them as being real. Here is the behavior I expect, and I see it in this simple case:

```
In[1]:= FullSimplify[Sqrt[b^2], b \[Element] Reals]

Out[1]= Abs[b]
```

This is fine, but when I try something just slightly more complex it fails entirely:

```
In[2]:= FullSimplify[Sqrt[b^2 + b^4], b \[Element] Reals]

Out[2]= Sqrt[b^2 + b^4]
```

It seems clear that the result should be `Abs[b]*Sqrt[1+b^2]`. I have tried adding `//PowerExpand` as well as `Assuming[b \[Element] Reals, FullSimplify[Sqrt[b^2 + b^4]]]` and neither gives the expected result.

Comment: `Assuming[Element[b, Reals],
 Simplify /@ ((Sqrt[b^2 + b^4] // Factor) /. 
    Sqrt[x_ y_] :> Sqrt[x] Sqrt[y])]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To exemplify @mikado's suggestion:

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[b^2 + b^4], {b} \[Element] Reals, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (Simplify`SimplifyCount[#] + 
     Total@Cases[#, Power[_, p_?NumericQ] :> Abs[p], Infinity] &)]
(* Sqrt[1 + b^2] Abs[b]  *)
```

To further encourage low-power output, increase the coefficient of `Total@...`:

```
 ComplexityFunction -> (Simplify`SimplifyCount[#] + 
     5 * Total@Cases[#, Power[_, p_?NumericQ] :> Abs[p], Infinity] &)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica doesn't agree that the second result is simpler.  It judges complexity (in part) by `LeafCount`.  The second expression has a slightly higher value.

```
LeafCount[Sqrt[b^2 + b^4]]
(* 11 *)

LeafCount[Abs[b] Sqrt[1 + b^2]]
(* 12 *)
```

You might be able to use a custom `ComplexityFunction` to get round this, but I would find another route to achieve this simplification.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sqrt[b^2 + b^4] // Factor // PowerExpand
```

gets you close.

Comment: Using `PowerExpand[#, {b^2}] &` instead of just `PowerExpand` gets you closer.